# UITextField Gradient Background Colour

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to create a UITextField that has a gradient background, moving between 2 colours.

I would like to essentially create this effect -
[uitextfield example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wZBz.png)

I am building my view out programmatically and am not using storyboards.

I have tried to add an extension to based on other answers, around UIView, however this has no impact on my text field.

The background is still white.

```
extension UIView {      
    func setGradient(startColor:UIColor,endColor:UIColor) {
        let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

I can then apply this as so..

```
private let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let  tf = UITextField()
    CommonTextField.commonProps(tf: tf, placeholder: "Email")
    tf.setGradient(startColor: .blue, endColor: .purple)
    return tf
}()
```

However it does nothing. I have tried extended on UITextField instead, however could not achieve any results.

**Edit**

I have updated my extension method as follows

```
extension UITextField {
    func setGradient(startColor: UIColor, endColor: UIColor) {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
}
```

My text field is being created as follows

```
private let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let  tf = UITextField()
    CommonTextField.commonProps(tf: tf, placeholder: "Email")
    tf.setGradient(startColor: .blue, endColor: .purple)
    return tf
}()
```

Comment: The correction proposed by Sh_Khan works fine; what happen in your case? is the textfield visible at all? the text field is there but still white?

Comment: Yes, it is still visible, but it is white.

Answer (score 3):

Extension should be for textfield not UIView   , note use **self.layer.addSublayer** not **self.layer.insertSublayer**
 OR

```
 self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 1)
```

/////

```
extension UITextField {      
  func setGradient(startColor:UIColor,endColor:UIColor) {
    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient) 
  }

}
```

use

```
self.textField.setGradient(startColor:UIColor.red, endColor: UIColor.blue)
```

Comment: The textfield is still white, can it be applied in the way I have in my answer?

Comment: hmmm no luck, the textfield if still white

Comment: change extension UIView to extension UITextField

Comment: I have updated my question, the textfield is still white, however my extension and component as registered as above